# Changing the default apache port doesn't work

Tags: apache-2.2, port

I am trying to run apache and nginx together. I want that apache should listen to port 8080 and nginx should listen to 80. For that, I have modified the ports.conf to Listen to 8080 and also modified the virtual host configuration. After restart, the server starts without any error but I am unable to access the url.

/etc/apache2/sites-avaialbled/mysite

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName myproject
  ServerAdmin your@email.com

  DocumentRoot /var/www
  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
  </Directory>
  <Directory /trac>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
  ServerSignature On

<Location /svn>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /svn

   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Subversion Repository"
   AuthUserFile /etc/svnauth
   Require valid-user
   AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/svnaccess
</Location>

<Location /trac>
   SetHandler mod_python
   PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend
   PythonOption TracEnvParentDir /trac
   PythonOption TracUriRoot /trac

   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Trac"
   AuthUserFile /etc/svnauth
   Require valid-user
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080
Listen 8080

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Do I need to change something else here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to choose which IP apache2 uses globally](https://serverfault.com/questions/969782/how-to-choose-which-ip-apache2-uses-globally)

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Verify that there are no other Listen directives anywhere: `grep -ri listen /etc/apache/*`

Also show what netstat says apache IS listening on: `netstat -plnt | grep http`

Replace **httpd** with the name of the apache binary on your system

Comment: Replacing httpd did work

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to access the url with the port behind? ....com:8080 ?

My guess is that you intended to configure nginx to be running as a reverce proxy, but you do not proxy the traffic you want to port 8080.

Can you please post your nginx config, too?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone repeatedly reading posts like these, then head-slapping when it doesn't work, the older posts refer to older versions of Apache.

The file you probably need to edit to change the port is: `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Thanks to someone who posted a version of this, which let me identify my own problem:

```
grep -ri listen /etc/apache2/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that nginx is not listening on 443. Or remove the `Listen 443` from apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Apache under debian and Ubuntu uses a seperate file

as already posted under

[How to choose which IP apache2 uses globally](https://serverfault.com/questions/969782/how-to-choose-which-ip-apache2-uses-globally/969789#969789)

You can see that there is a ports.conf