# How to choose which IP apache2 uses globally

Tags: ip, port, apache2

I have a server with 3 IPs and what to choose which IP apache2 uses, so it completely doesn't use the other 2 IPs anymore and Port 80 on those IPs is free for other applications. I searched, but I didn't get any result that answers my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't know which distro you use, on Debian and Ubuntu the default host is Set to Listen on All.

First, under /etc/apache2/ports.conf there is the list, which can be Set to Listen only on specific ip

Moreover I would suggest to Set the default host under

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Instead using *, Set this to the ip it should Listen on

I hope I could help you

Comment: Wow! I already changed everything in my VHost, but the thing in the ports.conf made it work! Thank you so much! Only answer that helped.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the ip and the port where apache is listening using the directive "Listen" https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html

Comment: But where do I have to do this?

Comment: In Apache's configuration.

Comment: But where exactly? There is no "Listen" or something in the file

Comment: The [`Listen` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) belongs to the server configuration context. This means it could be anywhere in the `httpd.conf`, but not inside `VirtualHost`, `Location` or `Directory`, as it's a global setting. You don't see it because it has a default value to listen on every interface.

Comment: I did so now, but now the Website itself is not reachable anymore as well.
I added
`Listen iphere:80` & `Listen iphere:443`
to the top of my `apache2.conf`. iphere is just a placeholder. But I can now use other apps on the other ips

Comment: @officialcrugg pls run apache2ctl -S and show us, however it could required to Set the servername